# time function and comparison

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I create nodes that have different dptr_time, for example 8:00, 12:00, 14:00.
I want to find all the nodes that have dptr_time that are with 30mins of lets say 11:45. I can't find a time function, is there an easy way to do that in cypher

Answer (score 0):

Easist way is to store dptr_time in millis since epoch as numeric value instead of a string representation like "8:00". Numeric values can be easily filtered using:

```
START n=node(....)
WHERE n.dptr_time>[lower_boundary_in_millis] and n.dptr_time<[upper_boundary_in_milles]
RETURN n
```

Comment: But I also need the data to be meaningful, if I use cypher to look at it.

Comment: Instead of millis you could use yyyyMMddHHmmss as numeric value.

Comment: that may work, but if I need to do some calculation (for example 30minutes before dptr_time, I have to figure it out how to convert it)